# Culinary use for the green parts of lemongrass?

Tags: culinary-uses

In most recipes/applications I've seen only the white part of lemongrass is used. Is there any culinary use for the upper/outer green parts?

Answer (score 5):

The outer green leaves are a bit tough, and not a lot of flavor, but the upper section of the inner green stalk you can use for infusing in soups, curries, broths, etc.

Rough it up a bit, so to speak, bruise it and make a few slits with a paring knife, then let it sit in your broth or curry until you've zapped the last bit of flavor from it. Just remember to remove it before serving to your guests since it isn't exactly edible on its own.

Answer (score 3):

I dry and use in stocks that I later clarify/filter or in herbal tisane blends or to flavor black tea. A nice evening tisane I make is cinnamon sticks, lemongrass, ginger, and cardamom.

Comment: How do you dry it? just in a low temp oven?

Comment: I hang it or just leave on a sieve/drying rack.